# usar PHPMailer sin configurar SMTP

Tags: phpmailer

Buenas, estoy tratando de configurar phpmailer por primera vez. Me ha funcionado a la perfección por las guías que he leído, pero no he conseguido una manera de enviar el correo sin usar SMTP.

Quisiera saber si existe una forma de usarlo de esta manera, ya que me gustaría que cuando lleguen los correos, donde dice "DE:" aparezca el correo de quien lo envió.

Aqui mi codigo:

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
require("PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// VARIABLES
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["mail"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$emailTo = "correo@gmail.com";
$subject = $_POST["subject"];

//SMTP
//$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Username = 'correo@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxx*';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 465;

// ENCABEZADO
$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress($emailTo, $name);
$mail->Subject = $subject;

// MENSAJE
$mail->Body = $message;

// ENVIAR MENSAJE
if ($mail->send()) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('Enviado Correctamente');
          </script>";
} else {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            alert('No enviado, intentar de nuevo');
          </script>";
}
```

?>

Comment: Obligado a usar un servidor que realice el envío del correo y desde luego te conectes al mismo; sería que levantaras tu propio servidor SMTP o contrates el servicio; y coloques los datos para hacer uso en tu script. Solo espero no sea para enviar correos masivo SPAM el uso que la daras.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes mandar correos usando la función mail de php.

En la propia página del PHPMailer hay un ejemplo:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Your Name');
$mail->addAddress('myfriend@example.net', 'My Friend');
$mail->Subject  = 'First PHPMailer Message';
$mail->Body     = 'Hi! This is my first e-mail sent through PHPMailer.';
if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message was not sent.';
  echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo 'Message has been sent.';
}
```